# How to restrict the current date based on the hours and minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

Disable the current date if the hour exceeds the current date hours using javascript.

I tried like this  :

```
var d = new Date();
var restricttime = '<?php echo $restrictTime->time_restriction ?>';
var restrictmin = '<?php echo $restrictTime->restrict_min ?>';

var hour = d.getHours();
var minutes_hr = d.getMinutes();

if (restricttime >= hour) {
    if (minutes_hr > restrictmin && restricttime >= hour) {
        min_Date = 0;
    } else {
        min_Date = 1;
    }
} else {
    min_Date = 0;
}

$("#datepicker-13").datepicker({
    minDate: min_Date
});
```

I think the logic is not correct in this. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative date properties. Check if this works.

```
    if(minutes_hr > restrictmin && restricttime >= hour){
          min_Date= "-1d";
    }else{ 
          min_Date= new Date();
    }
```

Comment: no consider the rsetrictmin is 20 and minutes_hr = 30 and restricttime = 10 and hour = 2

Comment: To set the min_Date

Comment: When `min_Date = 0` the date should be yesterday and when the `min_Date = 1` the date should be today .. is this understanding right ?

Comment: if  0 then the current date is not disabled , else its disabled